# The meaning of: O__b_variable_function__b__

Tags: programming-languages, el, oracle-adf

I'm working with Oracle ADF, and using JSF pages. Following some tutorials, I see such "nonsense" statements as: `O__b_variable_function__b__`

The logic should be: `#{variable.function == true ? 'a' : 'b'}` 
But I don't understand the strange markup with underscores.

Does anyone know what kind of language the "underscore markup" comes from? Would help me with debugging :)

Examlple (about half way down on the page - Example 3 - Stamped SparkCharts): http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29049_01/apirefs.1112/e17490/tagdoc/dvt_pivotTable.html

Comment: The term for this is "name mangling"

Comment: Why is it used, instead of regular expressions?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. They are not even slightly related.

Comment: My guess this is some kind of tag that gets replaced by a macro.

Answer (score 1):

If you look more carefully at the code the item you ask about is the **name** of the facet - not a property and so we would not use expression language to set it.
As Marcin points out it is simply a name mangle - what's the problem?

```
facetname="O___b_cellData_dataIsTotal__b__"
```

Comment: The problem is, that the component is a swithcer. The switcher selects the correct facet, with help from the facetname. If the facetname is O___b_cellData_dataIsTotal__b__, then there is no reason to use a switcher.